# Swiper Slider – removing the arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I would like to remove arrows on iDangerous Swiper Slider unless the arrows are needed. For example, I currently have 4 images side by side. If a user is on a mobile device (or a smaller computer screen), and less than 4 images show up, then I want the arrows to show up so that the user can scroll. However, if all 4 of the images show up, then I don't want the arrows to appear.

I tried to do this with jQuery, but the following code doesn't work:

```html
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                    slidesPerView: 4,
                    slidesPerGroup: 4,
                    loopedSlides: 4,
                    centeredSlides: false,
                    spaceBetween: 0,
                    grabCursor: true,
                    loop:false,
                    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
                    paginationClickable: true,
                    breakpoints: {
                        1200: {
                            slidesPerView: 4,
                            loopedSlides: 4,
                            spaceBetween: 10
                        },
                        1024: {
                            slidesPerView: 3,
                            loopedSlides: 3,
                            spaceBetween: 10
                        },
                        768: {
                            slidesPerView: 2,
                            loopedSlides: 2,
                            spaceBetween: 10
                        },
                        675: {
                            slidesPerView: 1,
                            loopedSlides: 1,
                            spaceBetween: 20
                        }
                    }
                });
    document.querySelector('.prepend-2-slides').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      swiper.prependSlide([
        '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide ' + (--prependNumber) + '</div>',
        '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide ' + (--prependNumber) + '</div>'
        ]);
    });
    document.querySelector('.prepend-slide').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      swiper.prependSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Slide ' + (--prependNumber) + '</div>');
    });
    document.querySelector('.append-slide').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      swiper.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Slide ' + (++appendNumber) + '</div>');
    });
    document.querySelector('.append-2-slides').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      swiper.appendSlide([
        '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide ' + (++appendNumber) + '</div>',
        '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide ' + (++appendNumber) + '</div>'
        ]);
    });
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide');
    var arrowPrev = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev');
    var arrowNext = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev');

    if (slides.length < 4) {
    arrowPrev.style.display = 'none';
    arrowNext.style.display = 'none';
     }
</script>
```

That didn't work. In fact, it messed up the slider (instead of having 4 separate images, I had one image across the screen. Then I replaced the last part with the following code, and it changed it to one image across the screen again, and the arrows were still there.

```js
var swiper__slidecount = mySwiper.slides.length;
if (swiper__slidecount > 3) {
  $('.swiper-button-prev,.swiper-button-next').remove();
}
```

Here's a [link to the website](http://arrant.org/)
Here's a [JS Fiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/deadendstreet/ja7m8t7z/2/#&togetherjs=FP27ymSs4Q) Strangely enough, the code that works on my website doesn't work on JS Fiddle, which has confused me even more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you please check it out i have created a snippet for you and i will explain i have created a function that check the view port as its defined in swiper breakpoints when the viewport **less than 1024** which is **3 slides** then the arrow will appear once is **greater than 1024** then the arrow will disappear as long as its **4 slides** as you wanted.

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/61LLnfh7/6/

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 4,
  slidesPerGroup: 4,
  loopedSlides: 4,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  breakpoints: {
    1200: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      loopedSlides: 4,
      spaceBetween: 10
    },
    1024: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      loopedSlides: 3,
      spaceBetween: 10
    },
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      loopedSlides: 2,
      spaceBetween: 10
    },
    675: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      loopedSlides: 1,
      spaceBetween: 20,
    }
  },
  on: {
    init: function() {
   checkArrow();
    },
    resize: function () {
   checkArrow();
    }
  }
});

function checkArrow() {
  var swiperPrev = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev');
  var swiperNext = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-next');
  if ( window.innerWidth < 1024  ) {
    console.log('Success', window.innerWidth);
    swiperPrev.style.display = 'block';
    swiperNext.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    swiperPrev.style.display = 'none';
    swiperNext.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.2.6/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.2.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked. Thank you so much. I will study your code so I can learn.

Comment: You're welcome that's good  please vote for it if its useful to you. thanks

Answer (score 7):

I managed to get this working using another way though.
I just wanted to show the navigation arrows when they were not 'disabled'.

On [Swiper API](https://swiperjs.com/api/) we have disabledClass, which is the class to be applied when the arrows are disabled (no navigation to be done, i.e. beginning or end of the slider).

```
navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    disabledClass: 'disabled_swiper_button'
  },
```

and then on the css side just simply:

```
.disabled_swiper_button {
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This is the best and most elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the answer too hence dropped here.
My requirement was to hide the arrows if the website was on mobile so
I used the following code to make it working ->

CSS ->

```
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

HTML ->

```
<div class="swiper-button-next" ></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to

```
console.log(slides);
```

And check and see what number it has at the the time its run.

Also fix console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at (index):449
```

Looks like this element is not being found:

```
document.querySelector('.prepend-2-slides').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
```

Comment: Thank your for your reply. The reply above got it working, but I'm going to try your suggestions as well so I can practice being a better coder. Thank you!